# Find time difference between two dates in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to find the time difference between the two given dates in the following format:
YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS

I have checked the examples, but they use datetime.datetime etc, no specific format of date and time.

Comment: You'll need to parse the timestamp string to datetime object first; for example for your format, you can use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). Please add more details to the question (see: [mre]) if you need more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime

dt_str_a = '2020-06-29 16:15:27'
dt_str_b = '2020-07-12 12:00:00'


dt_a = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str_a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
dt_b = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str_b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(dt_b - dt_a)
print((dt_b - dt_a).days)
```

->

```
12 days, 19:44:33    # <---- precise value
12                   # <---- number of days only
```